# Difference or similarity between today, these days and nowadays

Tags: sentence-construction

As we frequently hear following sentences:

1. Nowadays, everyone has a smartphone.
2. Everyone has a smartphone these days.
3. Today, everyone has a smartphone.

My question is:

Is there any difference between nowadays-these days and today? I know that nowadays and these days show us a trend and they are interchangeable. But, can we interchange both of them with 'today'? I want to understand them in the terms of usage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again...don't accept it too quickly. Let others come and have their views. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that 'nowadays' & 'these days' are direct synonyms.

'Today', used in that way, *is* a synonym - but I think it smacks of 'Reporterese'.
I think it is a forward formation from the old style TV news reporter, standing in the rain in front of a famous building, grimacing into the driving wind & opening with, "Today, in the House of Lords…"

Answer (score 1):

I consider the first two to be identical.  The third one is identical in most circumstances but "today" in it's literal use can also mean "today alone".  If you were in a  class and it was halloween then "Today everyone's wearing costumes" probably means only on that specific day.  In the case that you're working with a team that all require smartphones which the company is buying for them, then in the context of that team "Today, everyone has a smartphone" again probably means that specific day.  Since there's a possibility for mistake, I'd generally avoid alternative three.  The first two are unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

IMO...

The first two are the same. The third one is *similar*. It simply means the trend of having a smartphone is *on.*

But the tricky one is the last one *especially when it is viewed from different angle*. Though it certainly talks about the *trend*, the word ***'today'***, I think, goes beyond the trend and *might* talk about the **result**.

Thus,

> Today, everyone has a smartphone

apart from 'trend', it **may** also talk about the **result** of revolution in electronics and telecommunications.

Answer (score 0):

When we are using a language , everything must be placed in its own ,so three of them are just near to each other in meaning for I dont think we have got exact synonyms in English ,entries are only approximate .
these days means refer to yesterday the day before yesterday tomorrow and the day after tomorrow
today is absolutely today no more
but now a days is completely refer to this century or the period of time we are living in ...this decade and etc.
I am hopeful I could take you in ...